# Create a Swift framework with submodules

Tags: swift, swift-framework

I have an Xcode project with a main app and a Swift Framework called `Networking`. Now I'd like to split that `Networking` module into a submodule with only some utility classes so that they are available to the main app only when explicitly imported. So the usage I'd like to achieve would be

```swift
import Networking
import Networking.Utils

// Public class in Networking
MyNetworking.doStuff()

// Public class in Networking.Utils
// Should not compile unless Networking.Utils is imported
MyNetworkingUtils.doSomething()
```

So my module has the following file structure

```
.
├── Core
│   ├── MyNetworking.swift
│   └── Networking.h
├── Info.plist
├── Utils
│   ├── NetworkingUtils.h
│   └── Utils.swift
└── module.modulemap
```

I created a custom `module.modulemap` with this content:

```
framework module Networking {
  umbrella header "Networking.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }

  explicit module Utils {
      header "NetworkingUtils.h"

  }
}
```

This creates the `Networking` module but the problem is that the `Utils` classes are available in the main `Networking` module.

The question is, how can I specify in the module map which Swift files (ideally subfolders) belong to which `module`.

The `Networking` has only Swift files so the umbrella `.h` files are basically empty.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's good option here to have two different modules: Networking and NetworkingUtils (second could have dependency to first).